# Help using ShortCodes to style whole chunks of the post

Tags: functions, shortcode, css

Recently my sites got hacked, forcing me to start rebuilding them from scratch. It's been ages since I spent time on them, so I don't even remember the plugins I'd installed and used. One of them, though, allowed the easy creation of ShortCodes and the "mapping" of text or, even better, HTML and CSS through them.
I had used this extensively to style bits and pieces of the posts like in-post Notes, marked as...

```
[Note]Blah-blah...[/Note]
```

...adding a custom class "around" the text to allow for extra styling, or...

```
[AuthorOpinion=X]Blah-blah...[/AuthorOpinion]
```

...that slapped a whole bunch of DIVs and, depending on author class, a different image as well as "his/her opinion on some matter" (the "blah-blah's")...

...but, also...

```
[PostIntro=BlahBlah]
```

...that was "self-contained" and didn't need "closing", with the "Blah-Blah" styled in a more bold way. And a YouTube one. And some other "boxes" of the kind.

Now, I don't remember what plugin that was but, at the same time, since this functionality is supposedly easy to implement directly through WP, I'd prefer doing it "the manual way". Problem is, I've spent the better part of the last six hours copy-pasting code I couldn't make to work, for I suck @PHP.

I managed to make this work:

```
function postnote_function( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="note">' . $content . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('note', 'postnote_function');
```

...but, for the life of me, I can't make the aforementioned "[Postintro=Blahblah]" work. Every example I saw uses arrays "to feed/pass parameters to functions", but I don't need different "parameters": I need the first paragraph. And, for some reason, no matter how much I prodded the code, it doesn't work for me.

At the moment, my latest non-working copy-paste was this:

```
function postintro_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type' => '',
            'icon' => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        '[postintro]'
    );

    // Return custom embed code
    return '<div class="postintro">' . $content . '</div>';

}
add_shortcode( '[postintro]', 'postintro_shortcode' );
```

Any help? Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

**Multiple unnamed parameters, starting with equals sign.**

```
function postintro_bb_shortcode( $atts ) {
  // remove equals sign from first unnamed param
  if ( isset( $atts[0] ) && strpos( $atts[0], '=' ) !== false ) {
    $atts[0] = substr( $atts[0], 1 );
  }
  // Param array to string
  $intro = is_array( $atts ) ? implode( ' ', $atts ) : '';
  return '<div class="postintro">' . esc_html( $intro ) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'postintro_bb', 'postintro_bb_shortcode' );
```

> [postintro_bb=Vivamus sit amet turpis ultricies lorem dignissim sollicitudin id in ex]

**Unnamed parameter with closing tag**

```
function source_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  // remove equals sign from first unnamed param
  if ( isset( $atts[0] ) && strpos( $atts[0], '=' ) !== false ) {
    $atts[0] = substr( $atts[0], 1 );
  }
  return '<a href="' . esc_url( $atts[0] ) . '">' . esc_html( $content ) . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'source', 'postintro_b_shortcode' );
```

> [source="http://www.example.com/"]test[/source]

---

**EDIT**

Here's few ways how to define and use custom shortcodes.

**Shortcode with closing tag**

```
function postintro_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {
  return '<div class="postintro">' . $content . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'postintro', 'postintro_shortcode' );
```

> [postintro]test[/postintro]

**Self closing shortcode tag.**

*Apparently unnamed parameters work too.*

```
function postintro_b_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $intro = ! empty( $atts[0] ) ? $atts[0] : '';
  return '<div class="postintro">' . $intro . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'postintro_b', 'postintro_b_shortcode' );
```

> [postintro_b blahblah]

**Self-closing shortcode tag with named parameter.**

```
function postintro_c_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $intro = ! empty( $atts['intro'] ) ? $atts['intro'] : '';
  return '<div class="postintro">' . $intro . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'postintro_c', 'postintro_c_shortcode' );
```

> [postintro_c intro="afdfds"]

---

**Original answer**

The shortcode API is freaking out, because your shortcode name has brackets. Change

```
add_shortcode( '[postintro]', 'postintro_shortcode' );
```

to

```
add_shortcode( 'postintro', 'postintro_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't work :-(

Comment: @ducklord I updated my answer with more examples. I tested them all on my local WP install and they work. Can you get your code working with these examples?

Comment: Something is very, very wrong in my case...

Comment: I tried this piece of your code:

function postintro_b_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $intro = ! empty( $atts[0] ) ? $atts[0] : '';
  return '<div class="postintro">' . $intro . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'postintro_b', 'postintro_b_shortcode' );

...and typed "This is a test" after a "postintro box", just like in your example. It returned only the first "this" ignoring the rest of the text.

And, since for some reason I can't grok your code at the moment, what's the part that makes the shortcode "need closing" or being-a-self-closing-specific-word?

Comment: I should add that I'm looking *specifically* for a mix of your solutions, where I'll be able to add classes to "[postintro=blahblah]" shortcodes. The reason being that I've got *thousands* of posts in my blog already using this specific shortcode, since my before-I-was-hacked-and-had-to-scrap-everything era.

You gave an example where you define "the named parameter" ...(that = the text I type after it, if I understood your examples correctly), but how can I have the shortcode *itself* as "the named parameter"? As in, having an "=" *immediately* after the self-enclosed shortcode?

Comment: @ducklord, regarding the second example. You could try `var_dump($atts)` to see, if the other words are also present in `$atts`, as my example is only using the first index (0) from it. Regarding shortcode closing, using a closing tag, as in my first example, just makes the `$content` parameter available. It contains everything you write between the shortcode tags. Otherwise you can only access `$atts` parameter with your shortcode callback function.

Comment: @ducklord just for clarification, so is "blahblah" supposed to be the actual intro text or some (css) classes you want to add to the first paragraph of the blog post?

Comment: @ducklord In my third example "intro" would be the named parameter, yes, and "afdfs" the parameter value/content. If you use "=blahblah" without the named parameter, I think you'll literally see "=blahblah" in `$atts[0]`, similar to my second example. You'll then need to use e.g. `substr()` to cut out the equals sign from the string (to get just "blahblah").

Comment: I didn't have time yet to re-check everything and try re-implementing your code - I just fired up my editor minutes ago and came here to check for any answers. Thanks, again, for trying to help - I'll post an update soon.

The "=blahblah" is the quoted text. In other examples, I had boxen like [source=URL]blahblah[/source], for adding a differently styled box in the post flow, with a link to a site and a short note about it.

Comment: In this case, though, I'm just trying to make the [postintro=blahblah] "add a class to the quoted text", that I had "styled with larger and bolder text" (and was also using as the excerpt, but that's another story).

Generally, I'm trying to re-implement everything that was possible through the use of plugins, but with zero (or as close to) plugins. Next stop, finding a way to "read" the existing stuff I'd "injected" to the DB through Advanced Custom Fields. Then to create such fields in the backend to change those entries.

Easy-peasy for someone who doesn't REALLY know PHP :-)

Comment: Well, this was the result of the second example:

array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "This" [1]=> string(2) "is" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(4) "test" [4]=> string(5) "intro" } 

...and this after having changed the code to:

return '<div class="postintro">' . $intro . var_dump($atts) . '</div>';

So, everything IS there, but I only get "one string from the array"?

Comment: @ducklord, I added two more examples to my answer. One for [postintro=blah blah] and another for [source=URL]blahblah[/source]. I hope these help.

Comment: YES! Your...



    [postintro_bb=Vivamus sit amet turpis ultricies lorem dignissim sollicitudin id in ex]

...works wonders! But... Can you explain it a bit? What's the bit that turns the shortcode itself into a parameter (I mean, instead of having to do "[postintro text=blahblah]" skipping over the "text" bit)? And is the "implode" ("Param array to string") bit the reason I was only getting one word out of my arrays while you've pulled the whole shebang?

Gee, thanks again for this!

Comment: @ducklord I think that is the magic of WP. Anything you put after the shortcode tag inside the brackets gets put into the `$atts` array as separate items. As there's nothing the shortcode parser would recognize as parameter names, `$atts` has a numbered keys instead of named ones. That shortcode works with and without the equals sign, but it needs to be removed (the `substr` part) to prevent it from being rendered. Yes, `implode` is a native PHP function, that joins all array items into a single string. The previous example used only the first item with `$atts[0]`, thus showing only one word.

Comment: @ducklord You can mark my answer accepted to let others in the WPSE community know you're question has been solved.

Comment: Er... I think I did - I'm new to StackExchange, "I clicked the check next to your answer". Do I need to do anything more?

And, once again, thanks for this! You not only answered all my questions but also provided me with a ready-to-use piece of code. You're awesome :-)